How to navigate around the Rust types
Here is an example for iced library:
pub fn button<'a, Message, Theme, Renderer>(
    content: impl Into<Element<'a, Message, Theme, Renderer>>,
) -> Button<'a, Message, Theme, Renderer>
where
    Theme: button::Catalog + 'a,
    Renderer: core::Renderer,

How exactly can I find which structs/enums satisfy all this?
The answer in this case, according to docs, is to pass in a String. I know that in Rust a trait might implement new interface for a built-in type so I guess it makes sense, but I'd never have guessed it.
Can someone give me a few pointers how to approach this? Is there some sort of tool which can help me? I understand that this is a mindset and experience issue.

Your question will likely be closed as off-topic, but here is my advice, which I hope you will find helpful. Firstly it is natural to feel overwhelmed if you have never used language with such features. All I can tell you is that this will pass and with experience will come intuition. Once concrete advice I can give is that you can read documentation generated by rustdoc for those traits. It has sections that list which types implement given trait. This is a complex example, so it will be difficult to parse at first, but again, with experience will come expertise.

You might also find compiler's error messages helpful. When you pass to this function some invalid type error message should list as a hint a couple of types that fulfil those bounds. They might not be always perfect, but you might sometimes find it still useful.

Out of curiosity, did you try the rust book yet? I know your post is about navigating the ecosystem, but if parsing that function is overwhelming, you may benefit from something that will take you through the concepts more gradually (if you didn't already).

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I’m voting to close this question because code should be posted as text, not images, and the fluff should really focus on the technical question, rather than ranting.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I have finished with most of the Programming Rust book and got to the half of the Hands on rust book (which is quite light on Rust features) so I think I got most of the features. Maybe the Rust book has some nice chapter on how to use the ecosystem, I admit I just used Programming Rust as primary source.

@Jmb I was not aware of such rule. My apologies.

@MatthieuM. I fail to comprehend the "rant" part, my intention was to ask a concrete question about how others resolve function signatures/arguments as it can get quite large. Surely there must be some methodology which relaxes cognitive load.

@I_Have_A_Name: in the first revision of your question you were talking about "blizzard" of traits, "Venn diagrams", "flow chart", etc...

There's not really a workaround that avoids learning. The unfamiliar often feels intimidating, and using emotive language is a good indicator that one is responding emotionally to code. That's understandable but not productive.

@MatthieuM. Yes, I was and it served to illustrate what I meant, it was not meant to be a "rant" but if you understood it as a rant then it was my failure to communicate properly.

Immediately above the source you refer to is the following comment:
/// Creates a new [`Button`] with the provided content.
///
/// # Example
/// ```no_run
/// # mod iced { pub mod widget { pub use iced_widget::*; } }
/// # pub type State = ();
/// # pub type Element<'a, Message> = iced_widget::core::Element<'a, Message, iced_widget::Theme, iced_widget::Renderer>;
/// use iced::widget::button;
///
/// #[derive(Clone)]
/// enum Message {
///     ButtonPressed,
/// }
///
/// fn view(state: &State) -> Element<'_, Message> {
///     button("Press me!").on_press(Message::ButtonPressed).into()
/// }
/// ```

Which is a start.
In general the advice is the same for any language: breathe, relax, look for examples, documents and hints.
Remember that it's entirely possible to write Python which would be similarly perturbing for somebody from a statically-typed background, and unfamiliarity doesn't have to be scary. Just give yourself some time.

Promoting this from a comment: part of the confusion may be that you are not (in some sense) reading real code with concrete types.
You're reading template code, which takes some type parameters (which satisfy some constraints), and eventually generates concrete code for the concrete types you give it.
The convention in the languages which use this sort of static polymorphism is to just read the template and reason about that as real code. The "concrete" code is never actually emitted in human-readable form, and hasn't really been useful since the ancient history of CFront.
Anyway, this is why you don't see understandable types - just a description of the constraints the type parameters must satisfy.
For a library, it may often be the case that these types are expected to be supplied by the user (that's one reason for making them generic, after all), so they're not contained in the library code in the first place.

I am aware of the examples, my question was of methodology as it's likely that sometime in the future one might work with a codebase which has no examples or documentation. From what I understood rustdoc is a good place to start.

The methodology is to learn from codebases that do have examples and docs, and then apply your knowledge afterwards!

Understood, thank you for clarifying. I was under the impression that by using a statically typed language it would be easy to perform a code analysis by some tool and get answers in style of "these are the struct/enums which fit the function argument".

For a statically-typed language like C that's generally true. For languages with generics/static polymorphism and type deduction (eg. Rust, C++, Haskell), it isn't. That's because you're not reading the code, but a template which eventually generates code for a type that satisfies some constraints.

I see. Thanks for everything!

The practical advice is not to try to hard to understand it, instead start from the examples in the documentation.
Here the type impl Into<Element<...>> means some type T that can be converted to the Element type.
The trait Into is implemented as the inverse of From, so you need to find for which types T the type Element implements From<T>. You can do this by reading the documentation of Element, there is a section Trait Implementations where they are listed together (plenty of them).
I have not looked what effect the type parameters of Element have. The type system of Rust is Turing-complete, so there is no limit on how complex things can get. Usually it is better to try things and let the compiler remind you when it's incorrect. Over time you will learn which patterns work and use those.

Very solid advice. Thanks!
